# sql query for n rows plus another a row with id

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, db2

I have a query, which return (say)10 rows

```
SELECT EL.ID AS ID ,EL.x AS x ,EL.y AS y,EL.z AS z,  
              EL.k AS k, EL.a AS a, 
              EL.b AS b ,EL.c AS c,EL.d AS d ,EL.e AS e ,  
              EL.f AS f,EL.g AS g  
              FROM MYTABLE EL  
              WHERE EL.x = '2004'  
              AND EL.y = 'FYY'  
              AND EL.z = 'test' 
              AND EL.a = 'INTC'  
              AND EL.b = 321593
```

Along with this i want to join the row of same table (MYTABLE) where id =4  (1 row)
Which is the most preferred way using SQL server syntax?

Comment: Can you not use `or id = 4`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EL.ID AS ID ,EL.x AS x ,EL.y AS y,EL.z AS z,  
    EL.k AS k, EL.a AS a, 
    EL.b AS b ,EL.c AS c,EL.d AS d ,EL.e AS e ,  
    EL.f AS f,EL.g AS g  
    FROM MYTABLE EL  
    WHERE (EL.x = '2004'  
          AND EL.y = 'FYY'  
          AND EL.z = 'test' 
          AND EL.a = 'INTC'  
          AND EL.b = 321593)
    OR (EL.ID = 4)
```